# subtraction of two dates not working in bash

Tags: bash

I've been overthinking this I am positive however I just need to know the difference between the times.....i.e. how long it took from TimeB to TimeA as it tells me how long something took to run. This is all written in bash.

I have two commands each pulling data to bring in a datetime.

#Reads last date of log input and pulls time out

```bash
TimeA = "$(tac /pipeline.log | grep log.inputs.jdbc -m 1 | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}T[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{2}')"
```

#reads last timestamp

```bash
TimeB = "$(curl -s -XGET -k -u username:password URL/index/_search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"ACCOUNT*"}}}' | grep -Eo '@timestamp\"\:\"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}' | tail -n1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}')"
```

```
TimeA: 2022-09-21T07:20:00,34

TimeB: 2022-09-21T11:40:24.65
```

Using basic subtractions or anything seems to not present a real value.  Any help appreciated.

When I attempt to do basic subtraction ($TimeB - $TimeA).  I get

```
2022-09-21T11:40:24.65-2022-09-21T07:20:00,34
```

If the dates are different, will just provide an "N/A"

Comment: please try to rewrite this question with only the relevant data.  the only important part here is you want to compare TimeA and TimeB right?  Where that data came from doesn't matter for comparing the two times.  "seems to not present a real value" you should always include your commands / code, desired result, and actual result.

Comment: please update the question to show your attempts at `basic substractions` and `DIFF`; also explain what should be done if the dates are not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
TimeA="2022-09-21T07:20:00,34"
TimeB="2022-09-21T11:40:24.65"

epochA=$(date -d "$TimeA" +"%s")
epochB=$(date -d "$TimeB" +"%s")

((diffInSec=epochA-epochB))
echo $diffInSec
```

It ignores the floating part of the seconds (on which, btw, you have an inconsistency. One uses a comma, the other a period).
If you need it, the simpler is probably to extract them with a cut, and compute diff in 100th of sec

```
TimeA="2022-09-21T07:20:00,34"
TimeB="2022-09-21T11:40:24.65"

epochA=$(date -d "$TimeA" +"%s")
epochB=$(date -d "$TimeB" +"%s")
fracA=${TimeA##*:???}
fracB=${TimeB##*:???}


((diffIn100thSec=100*epochA+fracA-100*epochB-fracB))
echo $diffIn100thSec
```

I could have used `${TimeA##*[,.]}` to get the fractional part. But I guess, it would be easier that you choose one fractional separator once for all, and then use `${TimeA##*.}` or `${TimeA##*,}`